# I need help creating this macro in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to create a macro "ADD128 N,M" that will add two unsigned numbers of 128bits each in memory and will put the sum in the memory by N  (N=N+M)

I've been trying to get this to work for a few hours, and I can't get it to work at all. No matter what I try the answer will only be 0s.

Here is the code I need to add this macro in.

```
 PAGE    80,132 
;===================================================================
;                   PROGRAM LISTING 5.1
;
; 
;
;===================================================================
        .MODEL  SMALL,BASIC,FARSTACK 
        .386
;===================================================================
                                   ;PROCEDURES TO
       EXTRN   NEWLINE:FAR         ;DISPLAY NEWLINE CHARACTER
       EXTRN   PUTDEC:FAR          ;DISPLAY DECIMAL INTEGER
;===================================================================
; S T A C K   D E F I N I T I O N
;
       .STACK  386







SHL64 MACRO REG1, REG2
    SHL     REG2, 1
    RCL     REG1, 1
    ENDM

SHR64   MACRO   REG1, REG2
    SHR     REG1, 1
    RCR     REG2, 1
    ENDM


;===================================================================
; C O D E   S E G M E N T   D E F I N I T I O N
;
       .CODE
;
EX_5_1:
       MOV     BL,1                ;SET CODE FOR WORD DISPLAY
       MOV     EDI,0001H            ;LOAD AX WITH 0000000000000001
       MOV     ESI,0010H
       MOV     EBX,0001H    
       MOV     EDX,0001H    
       MOV     ECX,0001H
       MOV     DL,1 




       MOV      EAX, EDI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         ;DISPLAY CONTENTS OF AX
       MOV      EAX, ESI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         ;DISPLAY CONTENTS OF AX
       CALL     NEWLINE         ;SKIP TO NEXT LINE ON DISPLAY
       CALL     NEWLINE
       CALL     NEWLINE




       SHL64  EDI,ESI

       MOV      EAX,EDI
       CALL     PUT_BIN
       MOV      EAX,ESI
       CALL     PUT_BIN
       CALL     NEWLINE
       CALL     NEWLINE
       CALL     NEWLINE

        SHR64   EDI,ESI

       MOV      EAX,EDI
       CALL     PUT_BIN
       MOV      EAX,ESI
       CALL     PUT_BIN
       CALL     NEWLINE
       CALL     NEWLINE
       CALL     NEWLINE


        MOV     EAX, EBX
       CALL     PUT_BIN
       MOV      EAX,EDX
       CALL     PUT_BIN
       MOV      EAX, EDI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         ;DISPLAY CONTENTS OF AX
       MOV      EAX, ESI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         ;DISPLAY CONTENTS OF AX
       CALL     NEWLINE         ;SKIP TO NEXT LINE ON DISPLAY
       CALL     NEWLINE
       CALL     NEWLINE
```

This is the last part I need to do, and the only part I can't get to work. Whoever would help me would be a life saver!

Comment: Show us you've tried. I see not a single `ADD/ADC` in the above code.

Comment: I deleted it since it didn't work, and I was most likely not on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct macro for adding two 128 bit memory address locations is:

```
ADD128   MACRO n, m
         mov   eax, dword ptr[m]
         add   dword ptr[n], eax
         mov   eax, dword ptr[m + 4]
         adc   dword ptr[n + 4], eax
         mov   eax, dword ptr[m + 8]
         adc   dword ptr[n + 8], eax
         mov   eax, dword ptr[m + 12]
         adc   dword ptr[n + 12], eax
         ENDM
```

Comment: That would just be a 64-bit add.